# Encoding JSON in cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

```
 $cURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($cURL);
  
    curl_close($cURL);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
```

I take JSON with a Cyrillic, the arrays have ANSI encoding. As a result, JSON is obtained in this form
[image]

How do I get the correct encoding of an array? Or recode it? Tried `mb_convert_encoding` the same result

Comment: Have you tried either utf8_decode or utf8_encode? Depending which way you want to do the encoding. Try both